# How to Disable Web Feeds to see XML structure in Fire Fox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xml, rss

As a developer I frequently interact with JSON and XML values. But when I access any XML documents as in htt://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$format=atom 
the Firefox looks like the below screen:

[image]

which actually looks like this in chrome

[image]

How do I see my XML structure in Firefox, as it looks in Chrome now?

Answer (score 0):

The Web Feed reader will be removed in a future version of Firefox:

> After careful consideration of various options (which also included doing nothing, or investing heavily in updating the code), we've decided to go ahead and remove builtin feed support from Firefox.
>
> This will happen as part of Firefox 64, scheduled for release in December 2018. We will not change anything on Firefox 60 ESR, but the next major ESR branch (currently expected to be Firefox 68 ESR) will include the same changes.

**References**

- [Mozilla plans to remove RSS feed reader and Live Bookmarks support from Firefox - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/07/25/mozilla-plans-to-remove-rss-feed-reader-and-live-bookmarks-support-from-firefox/)
- [Firefox Bug #1477667 - [meta] Remove feed reader and live bookmarks support from Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1477667)
- [Browser.feeds.handlers -  MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.feeds.handler)
- [Browser.feeds.handlers.webservice - MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.feeds.handlers.webservice)
- [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)
- [Firefox Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts](https://www.accessfirefox.org/Firefox_Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts.html)
- [Navigator.registerContentHandler() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerContentHandler)